# Function of「果」in (folk, written) Cantonese?

Tags: cantonese

I've started going through《[男人唔可以窮](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=5961)》.

In [Chapter 1](https://www.shikoto.com/articles/383/384.html) there is the following paragraph:

> 阿爸佢教我好多野，放假會同我去睇精工對南華，去彭福公園睇人放風箏，直到我十六歲果年，有一日醫院打黎，話老豆於行動中，由四樓跌左落一個天井度，送去醫院果時，左腳腳底仲係插住一支八吋既生鐵釘。

I'm quite confused by the usage of「果」in these two instances here:

- 直到我十六歲果年
- 送去醫院果時

I'm not sure how faithful the copy of the novel on 紙言 is to the original -or- if it is the folk/colloquial nature of the writings, but「果」doesn't seem to have any definitions that fit the context.

[Words.HK](https://words.hk/) only gives the definitions:

> 1 fruit
> 2 result/consequence

[CC-Canto](https://cantonese.org/search.php?q=%E6%9E%9C)'s defintions:

> 1 fruit
> 2 result
> 3 resolute
> 4 indeed
> 5 if really

The jyutping gwo2 and even just gwo don't really pull up many other options even. It's all a bit confusing - any ideas?

---

Here's another example of「果」in context from chapter one of the book:

- 阿爸話佢改我呢個名果時

Comment: Here, 果 is just an alternative representation of `go2` (meaning `that`, more commonly written as 嗰, functioning similarly to Mandarin 那), since some variations of Cantonese pronounce Jyutping kw- and gw- as k- and g- (notably under the influence of phonetic changes known as 懶音).

Comment: 嗰時 in written form is 的時候 - when. 送去醫院嗰時 When (he was) sent to the hospital

Comment: @wang_xiao_ming That's perfectly good as an answer and not a comment, please write it up.

Answer (score 6):

Here, 果 is just an alternative representation of *go2* (meaning *that*, more commonly written as 嗰, functioning similarly to Mandarin 那), since some variations of Cantonese pronounce Jyutping *kw-* and *gw-* as *k-* and *g-* (notably under the influence of phonetic changes known as [懶音](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%87%92%E9%9F%B3)).